# coordinates from contour in matlab where level is zero

Tags: matlab

I have wrote a program using Level Set Function for curve propagation. Curve is represented by level zero in contour plot. How can I get the coordinates of these curve as I march in time?

Contour are obtained at every time step. How to get the coordinates at each step?

Answer (score 0):

A zero level contour from a set of points z(x,y) can be obtained by `contourc`. For instance, for the `peaks`-example of MATLAB, we obtain the contour lines with height 0 as follows:

```
c = contourc(peaks, [0,0]);
```

If this contour is a single line, this is all you need to do. However, the contour might consists of multiple islands (which is the case for this example), which means that you need to split the set of (x,y) coordinates in `c` somehow. A split based on NaN values can be obtained through:

```
c(:,~c(1,:)) = NaN;
```

and the result can be plot by

```
plot(c(1,:),c(2,:),'k');
```

If this is not sufficient, you could also construct a cell array `c_split` of islands:

```
b = find(~c(1,:))+1;
e = b+c(2,b-1)-1;
c_split = arrayfun(@(idx) c(:,b(idx):e(idx)), 1:numel(b), 'uni', 0)';
```

and the visualisation is very similar:

```
idx = 1;
plot(c_split{idx}(1,:),c_split{idx}(2,:),'k');
```

If the contours need to be stored for multiple time steps, you combine all results into a cell:

```
c_all{idx} = c;
```